# working with XML in PHP

Tags: php

I have an url return an XML page result. When I use this command:

```
print_r(file($url));
```

Its done, but when I use command:

```
$doc =  load($url);
```

after that I :

```
print_r($doc);
```

it out. Its print_r out nothing. I'm quite new in work with XML in PHP someone give advise, please! 
Thank you for your attention!

Comment: What is `load()` supposed to be doing?

Comment: +1 deceze, give us the revelant code part ...

Comment: It might only seem like nothing is printed out. As far as I understand, you are doing something with XML - therefore I assume that the tags are not escaped and thus interpreted as invalid HTML tags by the browser. As a result, nothing is displayed. You could check this by viewing the source of the page...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really sure what you trying to do but for parsing an xml file in PHP there two main ways: [DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php)

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML(file_get_contents($url));
```

[SimpleXML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents($xmlstr));
```

[file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) Reads entire file into a string

Comment: I'm using simplexml_load_file and get the same result like you suggest RageZ. But the result have many nested SimpleXMLElement Object
children. To deal with this I have to waste a lot of time and I'm in hurry now! :D

Comment: @gacon: you should use `xpath` to get only the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

@deceze and RageZ:
I'm using load() to get its attribute like this

```
$url = 'web address return an XML result';
$xml = load($url);
$node1 = $xml->getElmentsByTagName('tagname');
$value = $node1->getAttribute('attribute1');
```

But I have an error $xml is not an object and I check out by print_r and I get nothing but with print_r(file($url)) its print out an array as I expect!
@Franz: May be I get an error tag in XML file but I could not fixed this just work with the result!

Comment: Etiquette is to update your question if you have more info to add.

Comment: AFAIK `load()` is not a PHP function. So again, what does it do? Are you sure it does anything?

Answer (score 0):

You could also unserialize the xml into a php array and use print_r(array). Take a look here: http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/xml-php-pear-xml_serializer/3#

You will need a PEAR package for this